Automate API Calls in Power BI
I am looking for a way to make API Calls in Power BI through buttons or Power Automate which would call that specific data from database, but I can't connect my dashboard to the database directly I have to make an GET request via API that will send back the desired data to Power BI and then onto an already created dashboard with basic schema as it's base(i.e. saved in .pbit format link to data as per viewers request then show it). The database already has RLS implemented so users can view only the data available to them, and API returns data in json form
P.S. --> The database is not on any Microsoft platform, and not very experienced with Power BI as well
How should I go about it ??
I was looking into options for this and found either I use Power Automate or JavaScript or Python that does API Calling but didn't went too far

Does it need to be a button in Power BI? Can it be a data source, like this?

@NickA, I need to manually alter source data; as RLS is implemented every user will have different source data but same dashboard layout, but as we apply filters the source data will change accordingly i.e. I need attendance for yesterday or last 30 days so with change in filter I have to call the dataset again and refresh the source data on the dashboard will it be possible to integrate that functionality with M Query ?

Having buttons on a Power BI report change the data source is not possible, since the report will be seen by many users all attempting the change the one underlying dataset. Can you help me understand why you cannot pull all the data into the report, use RLS to filter that data per user, and then add slicers to the report to filter the data more?

@NickA, It's company's policy to not link the data directly with the dashboard so I have to make API calls in order to fetch the data when used and this dashboard will be up on a website where the users can operate or check report on dashboard, but instead of it being a button I can change it to an automated process like as soon as slicer value changes it will send the API call or request as per values selected, the only restriction is I can't use the database directly.
